# WIX React Native Navigation: Show side drawer in tab based app

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using React Native Navigation v2 from WIX in my RN project. For Dashboard(goToDahboard) stack I need to show hamburger icon on the left on on click show side drawer. How can this be implemented?

Since upgrading from v1, side menu options has changed and the docs aren't clear enough.

```
export const goToDashboard = () =>
  Promise.all([
    Icon.getImageSource('home', 22, '#272727'),
    Icon.getImageSource('th-list', 22, '#272727'),
  ]).then(sources => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
      root: {
        bottomTabs: {
          children: [
            {
              stack: {
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'Dashboard',
                    },
                  },
                ],
                options: {
                  bottomTab: {
                    icon: sources[0],
                    text: 'Dashboard',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
            {
              stack: {
                children: [
                  {
                    component: {
                      name: 'Settings',
                    },
                  },
                ],
                options: {
                  bottomTab: {
                    icon: sources[1],
                    text: 'Settings',
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          ],
          id: 'bottomTabs',
        },
      },
    });
  });

export const goToAuth = () =>
  Navigation.setRoot({
    root: {
      stack: {
        id: 'Login',
        children: [
          {
            component: {
              name: 'Login',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'am using like this, thats my code;

```
Navigation.setRoot({
    root:{
        sideMenu:{
            left:{
                component:{
                    name:'app.Main.SideDrawer'
                }
            },
            center:{
                bottomTabs:{
                    id: 'MainAppBottomTab',
                    children:[
                        {
                            stack:{
                                children:[
                                    {
                                        component:{
                                            name: 'app.Main.Bottom_1',
                                            options:{
                                                bottomTab:{
                                                    text: "Bottom 1",
                                                    icon: require('./../../assets/images/Bottom_1.png'),
                                                }
                                            },
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                options: {
                                    bottomTab: {
                                        text: 'Bottom 1',
                                    },
                                    bottomTabs:{
                                        backgroundColor: ColorTable.orange,
                                        animate:false,
                                    },
                                    topBar:{
                                        title:{
                                            text: 'Bottom 1',
                                        },
                                        leftButtons:[
                                            {
                                                id: 'btn_toggle_drawer',
                                                name: 'BTN_TOGGLE_DRAWER',
                                                icon: require('./../../assets/images/hamburger_icon.png'),
                                            }
                                        ],
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now we need to use wix's life cycle.

If you want to close it in SideDrawer, you should use the following code;

```
Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
    sideMenu: {
        left: {
            visible: false
        }
    }
});
```

this.props.componentId equal to app.Main.SideDrawer. Because of we are in app.Main.SideDrawer component.

If you want to open with hamburger icon, Go to whatever page you want to use for bottomTab, in our example I said Bottom_1.

Don't forget to type `Navigation.events().bindComponent(this)` into the constructor method. This allows you to linking with native.

Only the following command will work;

```
navigationButtonPressed({buttonId}) {
    if (buttonId === "btn_toggle_drawer") {

        Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
            sideMenu: {
                left: {
                    visible: true
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The code above works but is problematic. You're going to tell me that I'm going to have to press twice to turn it off =)

The solution is to use redux. Or mobx whichever you prefer.

To solve this problem, I used redux and redux-thunk.

Wix's is life cycle, please explore it: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Usage?id=screen-lifecycle

**With redux solution**

Real function is;

```
navigationButtonPressed({buttonId}) {
        if (buttonId === "btn_toggle_drawer") {
            this.props.toggleDrawer(this.props.isSideDrawerVisible);

            Navigation.mergeOptions(this.props.componentId, {
                sideMenu: {
                    left: {
                        visible: this.props.isSideDrawerVisible
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

toggle_drawer action

```
export const toggleDrawer = (visible) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        (visible) ? visible = true : visible = false;

        dispatch({
            type: TOGGLE_DRAWER,
            payload: visible
        });
    }
};
```

toggle_drawer reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    isSideDrawerVisible: true
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TOGGLE_DRAWER:
            return {...state, isSideDrawerVisible: action.payload};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Sample connect function;

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";

// actions
import {toggleDrawer} from "../../../actions/toggle_drawer";
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isSideDrawerVisible: state.toggleDrawer.isSideDrawerVisible,
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {toggleDrawer})(Bottom_1_Screen);
```

Don't forget to connect wix with Redux. https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/third-party?id=redux

I hope I can help you, I saw it a little late.
Have a nice day..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
Navigation.mergeOptions()
```

like this to fire and open the drawer:

```js
navigationButtonPressed = ({ buttonId }) => {
  const { componentId } = this.props;

  if (buttonId === 'sideMenu') {
    Navigation.mergeOptions(componentId, {
      sideMenu: {
        left: {
          visible: true,
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```